# How to select a one-or-more group ()+ to replace with the same group in VS Code regex

Tags: javascript, regex, visual-studio-code

In the source code directory, I want to move a file into a subfolder in current directory
example:
from

```
root/index.js
```

into

```
root/subfolder/index.js
```

In index.js I have many import lines like this:

```
import Styles from '../../../Styles';
```

The point is, I want to replace `'../../../Styles';` with `'../../../../Styles';`

Can anyone help me with that? I tried to replace `(\.\.\/)+` with `../$1` but It only returns `../../`

[replace with regex in Visual Studio Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGsHb.png)

Comment: I found a work around,
- Create the subfolder.
- Copy content of the file.
- Move the file to the subfolder.
- VSCode will ask me if I want to update the import lines (choose yes)

Comment: How about replace `^\.\.\/` with `../../` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/loWrxR/1))

Comment: You're not capturing the '+', so you're always going to get "../../" - make sure it's captured with `((\.\.\/)+)`

Comment: @bobblebubble that only works for the string that is at the start of the line.
In this case it's not.

Comment: add the `from '` in both the search and replace part, remove the `^`

Comment: Thank you @skara9 this is the answer I'm looking for. (Not sure why my comment got deleted before)